# D3: enter( ), append( ), exit( ), remove( ) chain

Tags: javascript, d3.js, append, exit, removeclass

Pulling from an external API, I am trying to create a small bar graph for each book title as you hover over it. Each graph represents the book's ISBN-10 number.

At the moment, I am only seeing the graph for the first book that I hover over. It does not change as I hover over others as it should. In my code I've used exit() and remove() to try and amend this, but perhaps I've used it incorrectly.

My D3 code:

```
    function barcode10(responseData) {

        var w = 125;
        var h = 150;

        d3.select("#barcode10")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

        var barcode10 = svg.selectAll("rect")
                        .data(responseData);

        barcode10.enter().append("rect")

                            .style("fill", "rgb(255,55,0)")

                            .attr("x", function(d) {
                                return 125- (d * 10);
                            })
                            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                                return i * 15
                            })


                            .attr("width", function(d) {
                                var barWidth = d * 10;
                                return barWidth + "px";
                            })
                            .attr("height", 15 + "px");

        barcode10.exit().remove();

    }
```

My html:

```
<div>
    <svg id="barcode10"></svg>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
#barcode10 {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: red solid 1px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 117px
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you want the bars to line up on the right, your `x` needs to be the total width of the container minus the width of the bar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, attr.("x", width - barWidth) worked :) I've run into some other issues though on changing up my code...if you have the time your suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: You need to handle the update selection.

Comment: The code you posted is not applying the enter/update/pattern correctly. Have you fixed that?